# Method not allowed (405) when deploying sharepoint 2007 (wss 3.0) solution from visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio, wss-3.0

I am trying to set up a Windows 7/ Sharepoint 2007 (WSS) / Visual Studio 2008 box.  Sharepoint is installed and running fine.  I open VS2008 and create a Sharepoint Blank Site.  I then try to deploy however i keep getting an error

"The remote server returned an unexpected response (405) Method not allowed"

I am more used to developing under SP2010/VS2010 so i'm a bit lost.  Any help/how to's/book recommendations using VS2008/2007 greatly appreciated

Comment: wss 3.0 isn't supported on Windows 7

Comment: I refer you to this: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2009/05/07/installing-wss-3-0-moss-sp2-on-windows-7-rc.aspx     and this: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2008/05/21/how-to-install-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0-sp1-on-vista-x64-x86.aspx         So yes it is possible to install wss 3.0 on windows 7.

Comment: Yes it's possible to install it, but it a HACK and you should not expect everything to work. I assume you're using the crappy VSeWSS with VS2008, have you tried deploy the wsp using STSADM?

Comment: That was my next step.  I know its a hack but it would have been nice if it worked as nice as my Sharepoint 2010/Window 7 box.  Never a problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

To go in a different direction: Create a Virtual PC instance of Windows Server 2003 on your Windows 7 box. Install Visual Studio 2008 and WSS on your Virtual PC instance and run it from in there.

Also, if you ARE using VSeWSS, download WSPBuilder instead from http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/. It is an add-in for Visual Studio and work MUCH better than VseWSS.